# Is read/write offset in per process table or open file table?

Tags: unix

When I prepare for my exam, I meet the following statement:

> If file1 and file2 are hard linked, and two processes open file1 and file2,
> their read/write pointer keeps the same.

Which, according to the answer (no explanation), is **wrong**. So I searched google, and found something different.

This link: https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/IC221/classes/L09/Class.html Says the read/write pointer is in the (system wide) open file table.

But this link [http://www.cs.kent.edu/~walker/classes/os.f08/lectures/Walker-11.pdf](http://www.cs.kent.edu/%7Ewalker/classes/os.f08/lectures/Walker-11.pdf)
Says the pointer is in the per process file table.

Which one is true?

Comment: The read/write pointers are per open file. You can even open the same file twice and will have separate read/write pointers.

Comment: @Bodo Wouldn't that mean they are per open file descriptor, not per open file?

Comment: Hard linked == they refer to the same file. This file (inode) may have more than one directory-entries pointing to it, so it may have more names, but **it is still the same file**.

Answer (score 1):

IHMO, the read/write offset clearly has to be a *per process* property. You could easily crash other proceses if this was a system wide per file property. This is my understang, but I'd rather have this confirmed by an informed source.

I took a look at the 1986 AT&T book "The design of the Unix Operating System" by Maurice J. Bach, which I consider a informed source.

In topic *2.2.1 An Overview of the File Subsytem* it sais:

> ... Inodes are stored in the file system ... The kernel reads them
> into an in-core *inode table* when manipulating files ... The kernel
> contains two other data structures, the *file table* and the *user
> file descriptor table*. The *file table* is a **global** kernel
> structure, but the *user file descriptor table* is allcated **per
> process** ... The *file table* keeps track of the (read/write) *byte
> offset* ...

This would contradict my statement. But then, clarification can be read in topic *5.1 OPEN*, pages 92ff. Figure 5.3 shows an example of a process having done three opens, two of them being for the same file, /x/y/z (I simplfy the naming here, and in the illustration below).

```
 User File
 Descriptor Table         File Table         inode Table
 +--------------+       +------------+       +------------+
0|              |       |            |       |            |
 +--------------+       |     .      |       |     .      |
1|              |       |     .      |       |     .      |
 +--------------+       |     .      |       |     .      |
2|              |       +------------+       |            |
 +--------------+   +-->| read offset|----+  |            |
3|              |   |   +------------+    |  |            |
 +--------------+   |   |            |    |  +------------+
4|              |---+   |     .      |    +->| inode of   |
 +--------------+       |     .      |  +--->|  /x/y/z    |
5|              |----+  |     .      |  |    +------------+
 +--------------+    |  +------------+  |    |     .      |
6|              |-+  +->| read       |----+  |     .      |
 +--------------+ |     +------------+  | |  |     .      |
 |      .       | |     |     .      |  | |  +------------+
 |      .       | |     |     .      |  | +->| inode of   |
 |              | |     |     .      |  |    |  /a/b      |
 +--------------+ |     +------------+  |    +------------+
                  +---->|write offset|--+    |     .      |
                        +------------+       |     .      |
                        |     .      |       |     .      |
                        |     .      |       |     .      |
                        +------------+       +------------+
```

The final answer is in the text following figure 5.3 on page 94:

> Figure 5.3 shows the relationship between the *inode table*, *file
> table*, and *user file descriptor table* structures. Each *open*
> returns a file descriptor to the process, and the corresponding entry
> in the *user file descriptor table* **points to a *unique entry* in the
> kernel file table even though one file (/x/y/z) is opened twice**.

To answer your question: The read/write offset is kept in the kernel *file table*, not in a per process table, **but** a *unique entry* is allocated upon each open().

But, why is there a kernel *file table*? After all, the read/write offsets could have been stored in the per process *user file descriptor table*, instead of in a kernel table, couldn't they?

To understand why there is a kernel *file table*, think of what the dup() and fork() functiones do with respect to file descriptors: They *duplicate* the state of an open file. Under a new file descriptor in the same process, dup(), or under the same file descriptor (number) but in a duplicated *user file descriptor table* in the new (child) process. In both cases, duplicating the state of an open file includes the read/write offset. So for these cases, more than one file descriptor will point to a single file table entry.